# Как задать родителя элементу?

Tags: javascript, css

Мне необходимо, чтобы body стал родителем p.
Не уверен, что можно сделать это с помощью css. Может, это можно сделать это с помощью JS?

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под "задать родителя"?

Comment: body и так родитель всех элементов на странице

Answer (score 1):

Можно задать потомка, так element.appendChild('p'); element будет родителем.